# Replace string if followed by any character visual basic

Tags: vb.net, logic, sql-like

I am new to Visual Basic. I want to use the `like` operator in a `textbox` to change a character if it is followed by any other character. But it should be on the `key-up` event.

Anyone please help me: how I can make the following code work?

```
Public Class Form1
Dim myString As String
Dim sMatch As Boolean = myString Like "x?"

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyUp
    If sMatch = True Then
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(myString, "z")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    myString = "x"
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and ask. Your variable `myString` was never getting it's value from the TextBox.  You just set it to `x` in the `load` event.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyUp
    If TextBox1.Text Like "x?" Then
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(TextBox1.Text, "z")
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TextBox1.Text = "x"
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: That works, but only once. Could you please suggest a modification to loop the code?

Comment: Its works each time you write "x?" in the box ! There is no need to loop. Each time there is a key up event the method will get executed. Now it depends on what your requirement is.